# Current User's Windows (Active Directory Credentials) in C# Application

Tags: c#, active-directory

I create a WebProxy as follows:

```
WebProxy webProxy = new WebProxy(HttpProxyUtil.ProxyHost, HttpProxyUtil.ProxyPort??80);
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = webProxy;
if (HttpProxyUtil.ProxyAuth == ProxyAuthType.MANUAL) 
{
    WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = HttpProxyUtil.GetCredentials();
}
```

Our `HttpProxyUtils.GetCredentials()` Method:

```
public static ICredentials GetCredentials()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ProxyAuthDomain))
    {
         return new NetworkCredential(User, Password, ProxyAuthDomain);
    }
    else
    {
        // anything else, just need user/password
       return new NetworkCredential(User, Password);
    }
}
```

This works great for Manual Proxies (specifying User and Password).

However, I need to also support silent Authentication.  We have a logged-on Windows User, and I need to get his/her User ID and Password and pass this to the `WebProxy`.

I'm struggling a bit in getting this to work.  Does anyone have any ideas or pointers?  Thanks!

Comment: You can't get the password this way. It's just not available. What you can get is a _token_ that was signed by (and can therefore be verified against) the domain controller that will tell you the username.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I don't need the password ... I just need to be able to authenticate against the Proxy Server using the credentials.  Any way I can get at those?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: For silent authentication, you need to use either NTLM or Kerberos, the latter being the preferred, cross-vendor industry standard authentication protocol.